# How to declare global variable

Tags: c#, ios, uitableview, variables, xamarin

I'm developing an app which I need to declare a string array like a global variable to use it in some methods but the problem is I can't do assign it.

my code:

```
        protected class ServiceTableSource : UITableViewSource
    {
        **string first = null;
        string second = null;
        protected string[] uuids;**

        protected const string cellID = "BleServiceCell";

        public event EventHandler<ServiceSelectedEventArgs> ServiceSelected = delegate {};

        public List<CBService> Services {
            get { return this._services; }
            set { this._services = value; }
        }

        protected List<CBService> _services = new List<CBService> ();

        public override int NumberOfSections (UITableView tableView)
        {

            return 1;
        }

        **public override int RowsInSection (UITableView tableview, int section)
        {
            return uuids.Length; <---- HERE'S THE PROBLEM!!!!
        }**

        public override UITableViewCell GetCell (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
            UITableViewCell cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell (cellID);
            **CBService service = this._services [indexPath.Row];** <--HERE'S ANOTHER PROBLEM!!!!  I CAN`T REMOVE THE [INDEXPATH.ROW] BECOUSE IS A LIST.


            if (cell == null) {
                cell = new UITableViewCell (UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, cellID);
            }

            **first = service.UUID.ToString();
            second = service.Peripheral.Identifier.ToString();
            uuids = new string[]{first, second};**

            cell.DetailTextLabel.Text = "UUID:" + uuids[indexPath.Row];

            return cell;
        }

        public override void RowSelected (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
            **CBService service = this._services [indexPath.Row];** HERE'S ANOTHER PROBLEM!!!!

            this.ServiceSelected (this, new ServiceSelectedEventArgs (service));

            tableView.DeselectRow (indexPath, true);
        }

        public class ServiceSelectedEventArgs : EventArgs
        {
            public CBService Service {
                get { return this._service; }
                set { this._service = value; }
            }

            protected CBService _service;

            public ServiceSelectedEventArgs (CBService service)
            {
                this._service = service;
            }
        }
    }
```

I need to use the "**uuids.Lenght**" to get the number of rows and use on the method NumberOfSections. If anyone have another ideia which works, I will agree kkk

I can't define the valor of the variable first, second or uuids because I the value is services.uuid and services.peripheral.uuid, and I can't declare services

Loot at the comments in the code.

Comment: Do you mean a static variable? A variable that is same across all instances of a class?

Comment: yes I try, but I need the value of variable NSIndexPath from the method GetCell, if I declare it as static the value will be "null"

Answer (score 8):

I think what you need is a static class, you can also store your variable in your application settings.

### Method 1:

```
public static class GlobalVariables
{
    public static string Global1 = "Hello";
    public static string Global2 = "World";
}
```

Now you can access these variables anywhere in your application like this:

```
GlobalVariables.Global1
```

### Method 2:

Follow this for storing your variable in application settings:

Solution Explorer => Your Project => Properties => Settings

Now you can set the name, type, scope and value of your variable. I am attaching a screenshot.

[image]

[Documentation for Application Setting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev12.query?appId=Dev12IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(ApplicationSettingsOverview);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5)&rd=true)

Personally I prefer storing my global variables in my application settings, but that's just me.

### Edit:

Follow this [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kirillosenkov/archive/2008/02/06/how-to-override-static-methods.aspx), I think it will solve your problem. Basically what you are looking here is overriding a static method but you can not do that, but luckily the link has workaround this problem. Let me know if this helped.

Comment: You're right too. But I'm using Xamarin and I don't find that way "Solution Explorer => Your Project => Properties => Settings"

And.. Yes, a static class but how I do a static class? It won't help.
The value I want is in the local variable NSIndexPath indexPath in OVERRIDEN method GetCell. 

Order of app works:
1 - Run the method NumberOfSections
2 - Run the method RowsInSection
3 - Just then, run the method GetCell.

So the value what I need get a value just when the GetCell methods run and I need it on the method RowsInSection...

Comment: Actually I need a way to use NSIndexPath indexPath in the method RowsInSection. This is the other way, but how?

For the app works I need to know the number of Rows per Section, What I don't know, because I'm getting services from BLE devices, each device can send me a random number of services, may be 4, 5, 6...

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about static variables, you could use this. The variable `NumberOfWheels` will be shared across all instances of class Automobile.

```
public class Automobile
{
    protected static int NumberOfWheels = 4;

    public override int getWheels() {
           return wheels;
    }
}
```

See this link here for example:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/en-en/library/98f28cdx.aspx#

Comment: Yes, something like this... But the method "RowInSection" run first than GetCell, so I need that value before itself get a value o.o
But I don't have how to assign the variable because the value I want to give him don't be declared. I don't have how to do it...

Comment: If I can declare it: CBService service = this._services [indexPath.Row];   in without the [indexPath.Row] I will can do it, but if I do it, show a feedback: The method CBService is obsolete...blabla...try .ctor()

Comment: You can change the static value of a class like any other class property.

Comment: No man if I use:
protected static class ServiceTableSource : UITableViewSource


The error says Static Classes must derive from the object

Answer (score 0):

I could be reading this all wrong, and if that is the case let me know and I will delete my answer.  It sounds to me like you want certain pieces of data (information about the services) available to you throughout all aspects of the `ServiceTableSource` class.  I'm sure you don't necessarily care how you get it, you just had the thought that maybe a global variable would help?

I think in order to solve this problem, you need to rethink the way you are using the `ServiceTableSource`.  Typically when it comes to applications that use a "Source", that instance of the "Source" isn't meant to change once it has been created. If you need to update the source based on more of your "services" being added, at that point a new instance of the `ServiceTableSource` should be created and assigned to the `UITableView` object's `Source` property.  In order to accomplish this, you need to create a constructor on your ServiceTableSource that takes in a collection of "services" and saves them to a private variable and does all the logic of getting data out of the services and creating your `string[] uuids`. By doing it that way, you have access to all the information necessary to create implementations for all the `overridden` methods in this class.

Here is my take on updating your code.  I don't have any other context around your app so I can't really test this.  Let me know how this goes and if there are issues, I can help you work through them.  Also, I'm not sure what you are trying to do with the event. A little more clarification on that would be helpful as well.

```
protected class ServiceTableSource : UITableViewSource
{
    protected string[] _uuids;

    protected List<CBService> _services = new List<CBService> ();

    protected ServiceTableSource(List<CBService> services)
    {
         _services = services;
         //TODO: Add your logic here to create your string[] _uuids
    }

    protected const string cellID = "BleServiceCell";

    public event EventHandler<ServiceSelectedEventArgs> ServiceSelected = delegate {};

    public override int NumberOfSections (UITableView tableView)
    {
        //TODO: Use _services and/or _uuids to determine the number of sections
        return 1;
    }

    public override int RowsInSection (UITableView tableview, int section)
    {
        return _uuids.Length;
    }

    public override UITableViewCell GetCell (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        UITableViewCell cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell (cellID);
        CBService service = this._services [indexPath.Row];


        if (cell == null) {
            cell = new UITableViewCell (UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, cellID);
        }

        //TODO: Populate the cell with data from _services and/or _uuids.


        return cell;
    }

    public override void RowSelected (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        CBService service = this._services [indexPath.Row];

        this.ServiceSelected (this, new ServiceSelectedEventArgs (service));

        tableView.DeselectRow (indexPath, true);
    }

    public class ServiceSelectedEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public CBService Service {
            get { return this._service; }
            set { this._service = value; }
        }

        protected CBService _service;

        public ServiceSelectedEventArgs (CBService service)
        {
            this._service = service;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: yeah! I don't tried it yet, but I think it will work.. I'll give you a reply soon